# PARTITION BY to consider only two specific columns for aggregation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

My table has the following data:

| REF_NO | PRD_GRP | ACC_NO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 12 | 1234 |
| ABC | 9C | 1234 |
| DEF | AB | 7890 |
| DEF | TY | 9891 |

I'm trying to build a query that summarises the number of accounts per customer - the product group is irrelevant for this purpose so my expected result is:

| REF_NO | PRD_GRP | ACC_NO | NO_OF_ACC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 12 | 1234 | 1 |
| ABC | 9C | 1234 | 1 |
| DEF | AB | 7890 | 2 |
| DEF | TY | 9891 | 2 |

I tried doing this using a window function:

```
SELECT
    T.REF_NO,
    T.PRD_GRP,
    T.ACC_NO,
    COUNT(T.ACC_NO) OVER (PARTITION BY T.REF_NO) AS NUM_OF_ACC

FROM TABLE T
```

However, the `NUM_OF_ACC` value returned is 2 and not 1 in the above example for the first customer (ABC). It seems that the query is simply counting the number of unique rows for each customer, rather than identifying the number of accounts as desired.

How can I fix this error?

Link to Fiddle - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=83344cbe95fb46d4a1640caf0bb6d0b2

Comment: Doesn't work. In this case it returns 1 for all customer references, not just the one in the example above - I want it to count the number of unique account numbers and return the count irrespective of the PRD_GRP values.

Comment: I've added some more sample data; apologies that wasn't clearer. Unfortunately the actual data is on a different laptop, so I can't add the DDL+DML as desired ;( But I hope the above edits help.

Comment: Yes, I have. No luck as it simply returns 1 throughout for every single row.

Comment: I'm trying to setup a DBFiddle...

Comment: @DaleK- I've added a Fiddle and inserted the link in my question. Would be great if you can take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need `COUNT(DISTINCT`, which is unfortunately not supported by SQL Server as a window function.**

But you can simulate it with `DENSE_RANK` and `MAX`

```sql
SELECT
    T.REF_NO,
    T.PRD_GRP,
    T.ACC_NO,
    MAX(T.rn) OVER (PARTITION BY T.REF_NO) AS NUM_OF_ACC
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T.REF_NO ORDER BY T.ACC_NO) AS rn
    FROM [TABLE] T
) T;
```

`DENSE_RANK` will count up rows ordered by `ACC_NO`, but ignoring ties, therefore the `MAX` of that will be the number of distinct values.

[db<>fiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9289393ec53ecc3ac9e4a69586574f2f)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `COUNT(DISTINCT T.ACC_NO)` which is unfortunately not supported in window functions. Therefore you have to write a sub-query to allow you to use `COUNT(DISTINCT T.ACC_NO)` without a window function.

```
SELECT
    T.REF_NO,
    T.PRD_GRP,
    T.ACC_NO,
    -- Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause.
    -- COUNT(DISTINCT T.ACC_NO) OVER (PARTITION BY T.REF_NO) AS NUM_OF_ACC,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T1.ACC_NO)
        FROM TEST_DATA T1
        WHERE T1.REF_NO = T.REF_NO
    ) AS NUM_OF_ACC
FROM TEST_DATA T
```

Comment: You don't *have* to use a self-join, it's still possible with window functions only.....

Comment: Thanks Dale! The issue with a self join in this case is that I’m pulling from a linked server, so performance is slower compared to Charlie’s solution above.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to implement `count(distinct)` as a window functions is by summing two `dense_ranks()`:

```
SELECT T.REF_NO, T.PRD_GRP, T.ACC_NO,
       (-1 +
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.REF_NO ORDER BY T.ACC_NO ASC) +
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.REF_NO ORDER BY T.ACC_NO DESC)
        ) as cnt_distinct
FROM TABLE T
```