# Query using analytic function for similar product

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find the query in order to match similar customers.

To simplify the situation consider this scenario:

I have a table which contains a customer name and product purchased.
customer name can have multiple purchases of same and/or different products.

Lets say the raw data is:

```
CustomerName | ProductName
A            | p1
A            | p2
A            | p3
A            | p1
B            | p1
B            | p2
B            | p4
B            | p5
C            | p2
```

In the query I'm looking for I would like to see the all pairs of customers which have at least 1 product in common purchase, and then to have all product customer 2 purchased while showing a count of how many similar product (distinct product) are between customer 1 and 2. According to the demo raw data, that should be:

Customer A and B both purchased p1,p2 and therefore they have 2 in CountSimilarity in every record this pair is shown. Customer B purchased also p4,p5 so they should be the significant output. Between pair B-A, they have same 2 in similarity, yet customer A also purchased p3, which B didn't so this is the significant output. Same happens for pairs C-A and C-B

```
CustomerName1 | CustomerName2 | ProductName2 | CountSimilarity
A             | B             | p4           | 2
A             | B             | p5           | 2
B             | A             | p3           | 2
C             | A             | p1           | 1
C             | A             | p3           | 1
C             | B             | p1           | 1
C             | B             | p4           | 1
C             | B             | p5           | 1
```

With the help of Tim, in my previous question, I made the following query, which is almost showing what I need. Unfortunately the count is too high - I need to count distinct product names, which doesn't work with `over partition by`.

```
select distinct t1.cname, t1.pname, t2.cname, t3.pname pnamet3,
count(*) over (partition by t1.cname, t2.cname) cnt
from MyTable t1 
inner join MyTable t2 on t1.pname = t2.pname and t1.cname != t2.cname
inner join MyTable t3 on t2.cname = t3.cname and t2.pname != t3.pname
```

Any suggestions how to approach this query?

The environment is SQL Server.

Thanks

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68249434/partition-by-to-consider-only-two-specific-columns-for-aggregation/68249522#68249522) questions deals with `distinct` in window functions.

Comment: Can you post your expected result here? if possible include the table schema and data as well. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query needs to be built up from `DISTINCT` values using `CROSS JOIN` imo.  Something like this

```
drop table if exists #dts;
go
create table #dts(
  CustomerName        char(1) not null,
  ProductName        char(2) not null);

insert #dts(CustomerName, ProductName) values 
('A','p1'),
('A','p2'),
('A','p3'),
('A','p1'),
('B','p1'),
('B','p2'),
('B','p4'),
('B','p5'),
('C','p2');

with
unq_cust_cte as (
    select distinct CustomerName 
    from #dts),
unq_prod_cte as (
    select distinct CustomerName, ProductName 
    from #dts),
xjoin_cte as (
    select c1.CustomerName cn1, c2.CustomerName cn2
    from unq_cust_cte c1
         cross join unq_cust_cte c2
    where c1.CustomerName<>c2.CustomerName),
similar_count_cte as (
    select x.cn1, x.cn2, count(*) similar_count
    from xjoin_cte x
         join unq_prod_cte p1 on x.cn1=p1.CustomerName
         join unq_prod_cte p2 on x.cn2=p2.CustomerName
    where p1.ProductName=p2.ProductName
    group by x.cn1, x.cn2)
select sc.*, excpt.ProductName2
from similar_count_cte sc
     cross apply (select up.ProductName
                  from unq_prod_cte up
                  where sc.cn2=up.CustomerName
                  except
                  select up.ProductName
                  from unq_prod_cte up
                  where sc.cn1=up.CustomerName) excpt(ProductName2)
order by sc.cn1, sc.cn2, excpt.ProductName2;
```

```
cn1 cn2 similar_count   ProductName2
A   B   2               p4
A   B   2               p5
B   A   2               p3
C   A   1               p1
C   A   1               p3
C   B   1               p1
C   B   1               p4
C   B   1               p5
```

Comment: I got an error regarding the naming in the order by, but I modified it to sc.cn1 instead of x.cn1 and that works! Thank you very much! 
Never seen the "cross apply" operator, I will try to read about it!